# raise KeyError(key) from err from pandas(python)

Tags: python, pandas

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\learning\pandasprg.py", line 13, in <module>
    col = df['Fare']
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__        
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc     
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Fare'
```

---

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
print(df.head())

output:
Survived   Pclass      Sex   Age   Siblings/Spouses   Parents/Children     Fare
0         0        3     male  22.0                  1                  0   7.2500
1         1        1   female  38.0                  1                  0  71.2833
2         1        3   female  26.0                  0                  0   7.9250
3         1        1   female  35.0                  1                  0  53.1000

when we want value of fare

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
col = df['Fare']
print(col)

output:
key error

so check the terms entered is correct or not

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
print(df.columns.tolist())

output:
['Survived', ' Pclass', ' Sex', ' Age', ' Siblings/Spouses', ' Parents/Children', ' Fare']

So copy the correct term

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
col = df[' Fare']
print(col)

output:
0     7.2500
1    71.2833
2     7.9250
3    53.1000
Name:  Fare, dtype: float64

Comment: your dataframe `df` doesn't have a key named `'Fare'` Impossible to know anything else without you posting your code

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us the code that produced the error?  Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If `'Fare'` is not a column but a row label, use `df.loc['Fare']` to get the row.

Comment: please fix your formatting